# После добавления maven в текущий проект не запускает java класс

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

До добавления maven у меня был один java class Main, после добавления его местоположение было в src. maven создал структуру проекта и на сколько  я понимаю мне необходимо положить мой класс в src/main/java, так? затем я попробовал запустить класс, появилось следующее окно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может я что-то не так сделал? или какие мне выбрать настройки конфигурации и что за ошибку с модулем он мне выдает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста структуру вашего проекта и сам этот класс, возможно его пакет неверный

Comment: и сам `pom.xml`

Comment: поправил вопрос

Comment: и Main класс так же покажите

Comment: хотя, кажется тут у вас уже не правильно. ваш класс Main должен лежать в 
`src/main/java/com/textwriter/TextWriter/Main.java`

Comment: мне самому надо создавать директорию? добавил картинку

Comment: Да, это называется пакет. Нужно его создать, далее в вашем классе Main нужно его указать

Comment: и еще, лучше в вашем pom.xml файле исправить artefactId, прописать его строчными

Comment: то есть каждый раз когда я в текущем проекте создаю maven проект я должен скопировать свои классы в эту директорию, предварительно создав путь после java

Comment: вы же в `pom.xml` файле прописали `groupId` и `artefactId` по этому он будет искать файлы по этому пути.

Comment: обычно когда в `IDEA` создаёте проект, он сам изначально создаёт нужную структуру

Comment: @ШаховГлеб, Лучше сразу создавать новый проект из Maven, а не добавлять в текущий проект. Потом проблем будет меньше ;-)

Comment: @Dred, я бы так и сделал.НО прохожу стажировку Team Lead дает такие задания)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зайдите в ваше окно `EditConfiguration` В нем выберите [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не будет так работать. файл ведь не там где нужно

Comment: пусть попробует, я специально сейчас создал проект также

Comment: возможно и будет работать, но это кажется не совсем правильно))

Comment: он когда установил новый путь до проекта, у него сбился classpath на no module. Поэтому Idea не знала откуда этот Main брать

Comment: блин, да я уже указал директории и заработало)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/968242/%D0%90-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-rebase

Comment: а вот с этой штукой объясните еще)